# Excel to Image conversion with Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.11

I have an xlsx-formatted spreadsheet file.
Now I want to use Python to turn the Excel sheet into an image.
How do I go about doing it?

I have previously used aspose-cells.
But I couldn't get it to working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Why do you want this? It matters. What you ask is essentially printing to a file, not a conversion. It makes a lot more sense printing to a PDF in this case than eg a multi-page TIFF or worse, a PNG image. In any case, whether printing to a printer, a PDF or an image the application has to *render* the document's contents into print instructions or graphics. That's not trivial, but Aspose.Cells does support printing and [saving to PDF](https://products.aspose.com/cells/python-java/conversion/excel-to-pdf/).

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what issue you are facing when using Aspose.Cells for Python via Java? Aspose.Cells for Python via Java does support Excel to TIFF, GIF, PNG, BMP, SVG and other image formats. Please try using Aspose.Cells for Python via Java 23.1 (latest version). You may also post your queries or issue in dedicated forums (https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.